# include/echo output of PHP

Tags: php, include, echo, server-side

I got two projects running, both written in PHP. Now I want to merge these two projects. The first project is a CMS and on a specific page i will display the contents of the other project / application. I don't want the first project to know about, or get access to, the variables and functions in the other and vice versa. So i just want the CMS, the first project, to receive the contents of output of the other project.

I don't want to make another http-request – using get_file_contents or cURL because of load-time. I find `passthru()` and `system()` hard to get working, but if that is a possibility, please teach me the way.

I also need to pass some variables from the first project to the other on execution, `controller_id` and `model_id`.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Iframes and load via javascript is not an option in consideration of accessability guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options you already discarded:

- server side integration at code level (include, etc...)
- server side integration via curl

You should therefore probably rely on client-side integration:

- load content via AJAX (best option for me): see Jquery load function, for example. You can pass any parameters, and data, and everything should work
- load content via iframes

Comment: it has to be server-side integration.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use an iFrame and pass some stuff via the query string...
allthough that's another request on load...

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you running?  You could always port the portion of the app that will, for all intents and purposes, be considered the "child" to a seperate namespace, effectively cutting it off from all the rest of the app and vice-versa.

Check out the manual entry on [Defining Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php) to see if it's for you

Comment: interesting... that covers classes, functions and constants.. that's pretty close!

Comment: i might go all the way down to php 4 because this is supposed to be highly flexible and mobile.